# Combined invisible fence with bark collar?

Tags: dogs, containment

We are interested in using both an invisible fence and a bark collar with our new dog. It seems a bit inconvenient for both him and me if he has to wear two separate collars for this. Do products exist that perform both functions at the same time?

Comment: I know this is not really an answer but: do you really need both? I usually distrust these kinds of automatics, because it is really hard to say what action the dog associates the punishment with. Having two automatics seems, to me, inviting a deeply confused, and therefore insecure and possibly dangerous,  dog. Having a real fence may not be an option, but for the barking, you should perhaps just consider training the dog yourself.

Comment: Have you looked at the Q&A we have on invisible fence and a bark collars?

Comment: What about actually training techniques instead of effectively torture? You may think it is extreme to call it this but I see no difference between them. Shocking an animal does nothing for helping it understand what it is doing wrong and quite frankly is lazy.

Comment: Geez, I love reading the moral lectures from people saying don't use either device. Our dogs are outdoor dogs on many acres of forest -- the invisible fence works great to keep them safe and within the 5 acre perimeter we set up. But one of the dogs sleeps all day and barks all night (I brought her back from Iraq, where I rescued her as a puppy, and that's what wild dogs in Iraq do). I'm not aware of any training regimen that will stop her from the barking (at coyotes in the distance, owls, crickets, branches -- you name it, and nonstop). A combined collar is what I'm considering as well. Seem

Comment: @JamesJenkins Where is the FAQ?  What does it say about this topic?

Answer (score 7):

Please, please do not buy either of these products.  They are illegal in many countries and are widely accepted as problematic by behavioural experts worldwide. They can cause a lot of suffering and will not keep your dog either quiet or safe reliably.

If you are going to use them appropriately and work with your dog to ensure that he understands borders and does not bark excessively, then you simply do not need either of them. Just train the dog, he is an intelligent animal, not a device: he doesn't require a remote control and will not benefit from the use of one.

The fact that both are available and there are people who use them does not make them a good idea.

Please see : http://www.apbc.org.uk/articles/shockcollars  for more information and other approaches that are humane, work better and are less likely to end up with a traumatised dog biting someone.

Answer (score 5):

I installed an invisible fence 3 months ago and placed flags all around the border about 10' apart. It took my dog a few vibration warnings from the collar to learn that she shouldnt cross the flags. She hasn't worn the collar since a  week after installing the fence and she has never crossed the line since. I trained her every day by walking around the flag border. I just got her a bark collar and hoping she will learn just as quickly so she won't have to wear it.